Running an Apache Sedona Spatial Join to DF throws a version error?
So I'm running the notebook from Apache Sedona here. I can get all the data loaded and printed out to a DF. But as soon as I do the Spatial Join with the RDDs
airports_rdd = Adapter.toSpatialRdd(airports_df, "geometry")
# Drop the duplicate name column in countries_df
countries_df = countries_df.drop("NAME")
countries_rdd = Adapter.toSpatialRdd(countries_df, "geometry")

airports_rdd.analyze()
countries_rdd.analyze()

# 4 is the num partitions used in spatial partitioning. This is an optional parameter
airports_rdd.spatialPartitioning(GridType.KDBTREE, 4)
countries_rdd.spatialPartitioning(airports_rdd.getPartitioner())

buildOnSpatialPartitionedRDD = True
usingIndex = True
considerBoundaryIntersection = True
airports_rdd.buildIndex(IndexType.QUADTREE, buildOnSpatialPartitionedRDD)

result_pair_rdd = JoinQueryRaw.SpatialJoinQueryFlat(airports_rdd, countries_rdd, usingIndex, considerBoundaryIntersection)

result2 = Adapter.toDf(result_pair_rdd, countries_rdd.fieldNames, airports.fieldNames, sedona)

result2.createOrReplaceTempView("join_result_with_all_cols")
# Select the columns needed in the join
result2 = sedona.sql("SELECT leftgeometry as country_geom, NAME_EN, rightgeometry as airport_geom, name FROM join_result_with_all_cols")

I run into an error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_279305/309031602.py in <module>
     18 result_pair_rdd = JoinQueryRaw.SpatialJoinQueryFlat(airports_rdd, countries_rdd, usingIndex, considerBoundaryIntersection)
     19 
---> 20 result2 = Adapter.toDf(result_pair_rdd, countries_rdd.fieldNames, airports.fieldNames, sedona)
     21 
     22 result2.createOrReplaceTempView("join_result_with_all_cols")

~/clone/ext/public/python/apachesedona/1/5/1/dist/lib/python3.10/sedona/core/jvm/config.py in applier(*args, **kwargs)
     55                     f"please use version higher than {version}"
     56                 )
---> 57                 raise AttributeError(f"Not available before {version} sedona version")
     58             result = function(*args, **kwargs)
     59             return result

AttributeError: Not available before 1.0.0 sedona version

Is this expected in the official notebook (it looks like it was updated less than 2 weeks ago?). If not, how do I fix this? I'm running with Apache Sedona 1.5.1, Scala 2.12.18 and PySpark 3.2.1 so my Sedona version is definitely above the 1.0.0 required version from the error.

Maybe upgrade pyspark version? I have sedona 1.5.1 and pyspark 3.5.0 and the notebook runs for me. Here's python script which worked for me. https://pastebin.com/VCYeE7ir  and the output which you can visualize on browser. https://pastebin.com/ugn3njPJ

This is a known bug and we are working on it. To fix it, please make sure you use the shaded jar: https://github.com/apache/sedona/issues/1247
Or, just use the SQL based Spatial Join
